# PHP PDO MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, pdo

Can you tell me what's wrong with my MySql syntax?

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO :submissionTable (project_id) VALUES (:projectId)";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO ".static::$_mSubmissionTableName." (project_id) 
         VALUES ('".$values[0]."')";

$database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
$query = $database->prepare($sql);        
$result = $query->execute(array(
  ':submissionTable' => static::$_mSubmissionTableName, 
  ':projectId' => $values[0]
));
```

Once I run this with `$sql` I get this error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
''submission' (project_id) VALUES ('1')' at line 1 in /app/model/ProjectModel.php on line 54
```

If I run the query with `$sql2` and without parameters it executes and inserts desired values. What's wrong with the `$sql` query?

Comment: table name cannot be bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304

> Please note this:
>
> Won't work: `$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM ? WHERE calories < ?');`
>
> THIS WORKS! `$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit WHERE calories < ?');`
>
> The parameter cannot be applied on table names!!

As you see on this comment, you can not replace table or column names with parameters in PDO.

But you can use variables to fill your table name or column names like

```
select * from $table where $column_name = "bla bla"
```

Comment: Thanks all. That was it .